# Matlab Matrix Rotation, Dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, rotation, linear-algebra

```
function f = flower(f)
t = (0:2*pi/100:2*pi);
x =((1+cos(5*t)).*(cos(t))); 
y = (((x)).*(sin(t)));
A = [x,y];
G = [cos(45),-sin(45); sin(45),cos(45)];
if (f == 1)
plot(x,y,'-g')
elseif (f == 2)
b = zeros(1,101);
z = zeros(1,101);
for i = 1:101
    b(1,i) = 2;
    z(1,i) = -3;
end
x = x+b;
y = y+z;
plot(x,y,'-g')
elseif (f == 3)
    A = A'*G;
    plot(A(1,:),A(2,:),'-')
else
disp('input a number from 1-4')
end
```

(using Matlab) I am having trouble multiplying a matrix to rotate it's image by 45 degrees clockwise. The block of code starts at elseif (f==3) I am getting an inner matrix dimension must agree error. How can I multiply Matrix A[x,y] by Matrix G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually look at the size of `A`, you'll realize that rather than it being `2 x 101` like it seems that you're expecting, the following statement

```
A = [x, y];
```

actually makes it `1 x 202` which obviously can't be multiplied by a `2 x 2` rotation matrix (`G`).

This is because `x` and `y` are both row vectors and concatenating them along the 2nd dimension (using `[ , ]`) causes them to be an even longer row vector. Instead, you can either concatenate them in the first dimension using `;` as the separator within `[]`.

```
A = [x; y];
A.' * G;
```

Or you could concatenate them in the second dimension but ensure they are column vectors first (using `(:)`).

```
A = [x(:), y(:)];
A * G;
```